# How to go back previous fragment from 2nd fragment using Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone help me, how to go back `1st fragment` from `2nd fragment` using the navigation drawer
 I have already tried with   `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`
but it is not working it send to Home Fragment 
here is code 
Home Fragment XML Layout Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

1st Fragment XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/select_product_video"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activities.ui.products.SelectProductToUpdateFragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentHome_SwipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/allContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewAllProduct"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:scrollingCache="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

1st `Fragment JAVA` Code
`OnClick` Method of `Adapter`

```
Fragment fragment = new ProductUpdateFragment();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

ProductUpdateFragment  Java Code

```
public class ProductUpdateFragment  extends Fragment  implements IOBackPressed {

    private SendViewModel sendViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sendViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SendViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_send);
        sendViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count>0)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean going back using the navigation drawer? Are you clicking back or are you clicking the product fragment on the drawer and it sends you to Home fragment?

Comment: @KaranIsrani, `this.findNavController().popBackStack()` will work for you

Comment: ProductUpdateFragment to 1st Fragment

Comment: @RakeshKumar where I add this line ?

Comment: @KaranIsrani, You might have back button and there you need to put that code

Comment: @RakeshKumar But  I  am using navigation drawer and 1st fragment is open from Nav Drawer and ProductUpdateFragment is opened from 1st

Comment: the button for ProductUpdateFragment  is in the 1st fragment? Then within ProductUpdateFragment  you hit back and get to home instead of 1st fragment?

Comment: use `onBackPressed()` method in the `2ndFragment`

Comment: @SharoneLev yes can you help me
also tried onBackPressed() but it is not working

Comment: @KaranIsrani the onClick method looks right, attach more code, something else might be causing it

Comment: @KaranIsrani, Did you try this `getActivity().onBackPressed();`

Comment: @KaranIsrani, update the code in the post that you tried

Comment: @RakeshKumar Code added for ProductUpdate Fragement

Comment: Do you override OnBackPressed() in the activity?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `tag` with `BackStack`

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, "ProductUpdateFragment");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("ProductUpdateFragment");
```

then you can do to perform `BackStack()` like this

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);

root .setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        } );
```

and `Override` this method on `Activity`, Where you implemented `NavigationDrawer`

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //super.onBackPressed(); 
         int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
         if(count>0)
         getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

Comment: added your code inactivity but now it is not closing App

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206132/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-and-karan-israni).

Answer (score 0):

**NavigationUI.navigateUp(Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment), dataBinding.drawerLayout);**